Given $a$ red ball and $b$ green ball, remove them one by one randomly until there is one color left, find average number of ball left
Question: Given $a$ red ball and $b$ green ball, remove them one by one randomly until there is one color left, find the average number of ball left
My attempt(via recursion):
Let average number of ball left with $i$ red ball and $j$ ball be $a_{ij}$
Then we have
$a_{ij} = a_{ji}$ , $a_{ij}=\frac{j}{i+j}(a_{i,j-1})+\frac{i}{j+i}(a_{i-1,j})$
thus, $a_{n,1}=\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{n+1}=a_{1,n}$
also, $a_{n,n}=a_{n,n-1}=a_{n-1,n}$
So, all values of $a_{ij}$ can already be calculated by recursion. However, I failed to find a direct formula for $a_{ij}$
I also conjectured that $a_{n,n}=\frac{2n}{n+1}$, but I don't know how to prove it.
Help is appreciated.

a red, b green !  I hope you don't mind if I change it to r red, g green, which is a so much clearer notation !
I shall use the shortcut way for finding the expectation, which basically deals with averages. (You can expand it using indicator variables, more or less like this if it is so needed)
Removing them randomly one by one is the same as arranging them randomly and removing them one by one serially.
$\underline{\texttt{Reds left over}}$
Consider the $g$ greens as $g$ bars creating $g+1$ "bins"
On an average, each bin is expected to contain $\frac{r}{g+1}$ reds, as is the last bin
Thus expected # of reds left over $= \frac{r}{g+1}$
$\underline{\texttt{Greens left over}}$
Exactly the same way, expected # of greens left over $= \frac{g}{r+1}$
$\underline{\texttt{Final Answer}}$
As these represent the pooled expected averages of reds and greens left over,
Average # of balls left over $= \frac{r}{g+1} + \frac{g}{r+1}$

I can't see how permutations are equally likely imply ending with red or green has the same probability, can you please clarify on it?

I have changed the wording as it was causing a misconception. It is not about the last ball being red or green, that of course, will yield different results depending on the proportion of red/green, each experiment drawing randomly placed balls until only balls of one color remain is essentially the same experiment repeated, and we are pooling together the results of such experiments to get the average # of balls remaining.

In general, the gaps between the reds (or the greens) are each expected to be equal (counting Start to first red and last red to End as gaps).  Thus the expected gap length, $g$, is computable as $$(a+1)g+a=a+b\implies g=\frac b{a+1}$$  with a similar formula for the expected gap length between the greens.
For your problem, condition on the color of the final ball.  Of course, it is red with probability $\frac a{a+b}$ and green with probability $\frac b{a+b}$.  If the last ball is red, then you are left with $a-1$ red and $b$ greens, so the earlier computation applies and you expect there to be $\frac {a-1}{b+1}$ reds (not including the last one) before the final green.  Thus the answer, in this case, is $\frac {a-1}{b+1}+1$.  Similarly, it is $\frac {b-1}{a+1}+1$ if the final ball is green.  We conclude that the answer is $$\frac a{a+b}\times \left(\frac {a-1}{b+1}+1\right)+\frac b{a+b}\times \left(\frac {b-1}{a+1}+1\right)=\boxed {\frac a{b+1}+\frac b{a+1}}$$
Sanity checks:
I.  Note that if $a=b=n$ this comes to $\frac {2n}{n+1}$ confirming your conjecture.
II. If $(a,b)=(1,2)$ the formula yields $\frac 43$.  In this case, the possible sequences are $(RGG, GRG, GGR)$ which give the answers $(2, 1, 1)$ respectively, making the expected answer $\frac {2+1+1}3=\frac 43$.
III.  More generally, the formula for $(n, 1)$ yields $\frac n2+\frac 1{n+1}$ as it should.
IV.  This function satisfies your recursion.
Side note:  one  way to prove the formula would be to remark that it satisfies your recursion and initial conditions. I do, however, think that the given formula is a bit hard to guess making this approach somewhat unsatisfactory.
